# Why can't this Python script get the file of "[]" in the file's folder name?

Tags: python

```
import os
import glob

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('F:\\workspace'):
    for txtfile in glob.iglob(os.path.join(root,'*.txt')):
        print txtfile
```

I can get the files with no "[]",and it can work if the folder name have only one of the symbols,"[" or "]".
I think I am using glob.iglob in the wrong way; but I don't know how to get the files I need without it.
Thanks for your reply.

Comment: The file "[]" doesn't match the glob "*.txt", so of course it won't be returned.

Comment: you dont need glob. you are already itterating over every file in your root. just check the file extension for .txt ? and then add them to a list. and then do what you want with them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Python documentation for `glob` mentions that it uses `fnmatch.fnmatch()` behind the scenes.

If you only want to match against the file name but not the folder name, try the following code:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:\\Scratch'):
  for file in files:
    if fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
      print os.path.join(root, file)
```

Comment: Yes,the code can get what I want ,but what if I want to copy these files to a folder.the fnmatch can't work.Do you have some ideas ?

Comment: The fnmatch will tell you if the filename matches "*.txt" and then you can use "os.path.join(root, file)" when you copy the file.